# Qt's QTableView and large numbers

Tags: qt, qtableview

[image: View of high number]

How to make it show large numbers in QTableView like 10030232145 and not as 1.02342e+10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard answer for changing how a view displays its data is to investigate your own [item delegate](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qstyleditemdelegate.html).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to override `data()` in your model class to return a `QString` formatted the way you would like for `Qt::DisplayRole` items.